# Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView not display list when using space

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have set adapter to the MultiAutoCompleteTextView in my android application.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchSuburb.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, sub);
searchtext.setAdapter(adapter);

static final String[] sub = new String[] { "Melbourne VIC 3000", "East Melbourne VIC 3002", "West Melbourne VIC 3003", "St Kilda Road Central VIC 3004", "World Trade Centre VIC 3005",
        "South Wharf VIC 3006", "Southbank VIC 3006"};
```

Its working fine until I come across a space while typing.

When I typed VIC it gives predictive results but when I press space it vanish. 
How to fix this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3abb0ddb14690e60?pli=1)